# Allow login to run stored procedure without being able to select from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server with two databases:

- Database1
- Database2

Login 'MyLogin' has read access on Database2 only.

Database2 has a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_LogData 
       @ProductID int
AS
BEGIN

    If Exists (Select (1) From Database2.dbo.Products Where ProductID = @ProductID)
    Select LogTimeStamp
         , ProductID
         , Description
    from Database1.dbo.Log Where ProductID = @ProductID
    Else
    Print 'Get_LogData: Unable to find ProductID ' + CAST(@ProductID AS VARCHAR)

END;
GO

BEGIN
    GRANT EXEC ON Get_LogData TO [MyLogin];
END;
GO
```

When 'MyLogin' trys to run the stored procedure, we get the error:

> The server principal "MyLogin" is not able to access the database
>   "Database1" under the current security context.

How do I allow 'MyLogin' the ability to run this stored proc and get the data from Database1, without allowing them to just run a normal Select query against Database1.Log

Comment: I assume you can't create the SP in `Database1` (which would more readily allow you to use cascaded permissions)?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/sql-server-execute-as-trouble

Comment: @Larnu No, the SP needs to be created under Database2

Comment: Then have a look at the question linked by @EzLo . Permissions, by default aren't cross database. I'll post (more complete) answer on the trusted option, however, it comes with caveats.

Comment: Is there not a way I could add 'MyLogin' to Database1, which would allow the stored proc to retrieve the data, but at the same time not allow 'MyLogin' to view the database tables or run a direct select statement

Answer (score 2):

This is expanding on the answer linked by Ezlo ([SQL Server EXECUTE AS trouble](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/sql-server-execute-as-trouble)), on which I'm going to cover [Enabling Cross-Database Access in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server).

Firstly, let's set up a quick test to replicate the issue you have right now:

```
--Create a couple of sample databases
CREATE DATABASE SampleDB1;
CREATE DATABASE SampleDB2;
GO

USE SampleDB2;
GO
--Create a sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable (ID int, Somestring varchar(25));
GO
USE SampleDB1;
GO
--Create a sample SP and User/Login;
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc AS

    SELECT ID,
           SomeString
    FROM SampleDB2.dbo.SampleTable;
GO
CREATE LOGIN SampleCredential WITH PASSWORD = 'abc123', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = BRITISH;
CREATE USER SampleCredential FOR LOGIN SampleCredential;

GRANT EXEC ON dbo.SomeProc TO SampleCredential;
GO

--Test
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'SampleCredential';
GO
--This will fail
EXEC dbo.SomeProc;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

As you can see, if you run this script, you get an error along the lines of:

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Procedure SomeProc, Line 4 [Batch Start
>   Line 28] The server principal "SampleCredential" is not able to access
>   the database "SampleDB2" under the current security context.

So, what is Cross-Database access? To quote from the documentation:

> Cross-database ownership chaining occurs when a procedure in one
>   database depends on objects in another database. A cross-database
>   ownership chain works in the same way as ownership chaining within a
>   single database, except that an unbroken ownership chain requires that
>   all the object owners are mapped to the same login account. If the
>   source object in the source database and the target objects in the
>   target databases are owned by the same login account, SQL Server does
>   not check permissions on the target objects.

Note, however, that there are **major** security flaws that *can* be introduced with this method. Thus, if this is a concern for your environment this **is not** the solution for you. Again, from the documentation:

> Ownership chaining across databases is turned off by default.
>   Microsoft recommends that you disable cross-database ownership
>   chaining because it exposes you to the following security risks:
>
> - Database owners and members of the db_ddladmin or the db_owners database roles can create objects that are owned by other users. These
>     objects can potentially target objects in other databases. This means
>     that if you enable cross-database ownership chaining, you must fully
>     trust these users with data in all databases.
> - Users with CREATE DATABASE permission can create new databases and attach existing databases. If cross-database ownership chaining is
>     enabled, these users can access objects in other databases that they
>     might not have privileges in from the newly created or attached
>     databases that they create.

OK, now that caveat is out of the way, what do to. Continuing on from the script above, we need to enable cross db ownership chaining on the server if it isn't already. You can do so by running the following:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'cross db ownership chaining', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 0;
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Now that is enabled you can enable `DB_CHAINING` on the **2** databases:

```
ALTER DATABASE SampleDB1 SET DB_CHAINING ON;
ALTER DATABASE SampleDB2 SET DB_CHAINING ON;
GO
```

You'll then need to create the user for your login on the other database, but won't need to give it any permissions, so this will be "fine" (it won't allow them to `SELECT` from, the table outside of the SP):

```
USE SampleDB2;
GO
CREATE USER SampleCredential FOR LOGIN SampleCredential;
GO
```

Finally, you can then test again:

```
USE SampleDB1;
--Test
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'SampleCredential';
GO
--It works (0 rows returned)
EXEC dbo.SomeProc;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

If you want to double check the user can't select from the database, you can do so:

```
USE SampelDB1;
GO
--This will fail
SELECT *
FROM SampleDB2.dbo.SampleTable;
GO
```

And finally the cleanup (for good measure):

```
--Cleanup
USE master;
DROP DATABASE SampleDB2;
DROP DATABASE SampleDB1;
DROP LOGIN SampleCredential;
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'cross db ownership chaining', 0;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 0;
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`execute as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.  It is unclear what the value should be, but to set permissions, often you want the *owner* of the stored procedure to have the permissions you want.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_LogData (
       @ProductID int
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS
BEGIN
    . . .
END;
```

Comment: I tried this but then it says the owner is now allowed to access Database1 under the current security context