# Best way to implement centralized stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, database

We've made a new database where we can store common data and stored procedures for our company.
*Let's say the name of the new db is dbcenter.
*We need to create a stored procedure (spGetEmpDetails) in dbcenter that gets data from an old database (dbemployees) and that stored procedure will be accessed by the new db (dbpayrol).
*when the spGetEmpDetails is being accessed, an error occurred that the user does not have access to tblEmployees so I had to give Read access to that user to tblEmployees.

My question is, Can I just give read access to the spGetEmpDetails instead of the user who is accessing it? so that if a new user needs to have access to spGetEmpDetails, I will just have to give access to spGetEmpDetails only and not to tblEmployees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow login to run stored procedure without being able to select from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235017/allow-login-to-run-stored-procedure-without-being-able-to-select-from-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into this article by Erland Sommarskog:

http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#crossdb

It lists available options for cross-db access which are the following, according to the artice:

> - Grant direct permissions to objects in the other database.
> - Enabling the guest user.
> - Certificate signing.
> - Enable cross-database ownership chaining.
> - EXECUTE AS + TRUSTWORTHY.

Obviously, there are pros and cons for each one. Enabling the guest user, enabling cross-db owner chaining or setting TRUSTWORTHY to true introduce security risks so you should consider those before choosing the implementation that best fits your requirements.